# Lilypond: How to separate verse and chorus while having guitar chords

Tags: lilypond

I am new to Lilypond and I'm using Frescobaldi as my GUI. I am trying to record some music that an older friend of mine has in his mind before they are lost. So far I have found some of them are older songs that do seem to exist on the internet but I am using them to learn the process of creating the Lilypond impressions. In this case, I have a song that has 2 verses as well as a chorus. I don't know how to create the file so that the chorus is separate from the verses. I am attaching the entire file since it seems fairly small.

```
\version "2.20.0"

\language "english"

\include "predefined-guitar-fretboards.ly"

\header {
  title = "I'm Free"
  composer = "William J. and Gloria Gaither"
}

global = {
  \key d \major
  \time 4/4
}
chordNames = \chordmode {
  \global
  % Chords follow here.
  r4 d1 g2. d1
  a1 a1 d1
  d1 g1 d1(d1)
  d2 a2. g2. d1
  d4 g1 d1. 
  d2 a1.. d1.
  g1. d1 d1
  d4 a2.a1. d1.
}
melody = \relative c' {
  \global
  % Music follows here.
  d8( e8) fs2. | fs8 fs8 g4 a4 b4 | a4 fs2. | %m1
  a4 a2 a4 | a8 a4 g4. fs4 | e1 | %m2
  d4 e8 fs8(fs2) | fs8 fs8 g4 a4  b4 | a2 a4 a4 | g1 |%m3
  b8 b8 b4 a2 | g4 fs4 fs4 e4| d1 | %m4
  a'4 b4 b8 b8 g4 | a4 b4 g4 fs4(fs1) %m5
  a4 a2 a8 a8 | g4 fs2 e4 | fs1 | %m6
  a4 a4 b2 | b8  b8 g4 a4  b8 b8 | a2 a4 a4 | fs1 | %m7
  a4 a2. | a4 g4 fs2 | fs4 e4 d2(d1) |
}

verseone = \lyricmode {
  % Lyrics follow here.
  So long I had searched for life’s mean -- ing, 
  En -- slaved by the world and my greed; 
  Then the door of the pri -- son was o -- pened by love, 
  For the ran -- som was paid, I was freed.
  I’m free from the fear of to -- mor -- row; 
  I’m free from the guilt of the past; 
  For I’ve trad -- ed my shack -- les for a glor -- i -- ous song; 
  I’m free, praise the Lord, free at last! 
}

versetwo = \lyricmode {
  I’m free from the guilt that I car -- ried, 
  From that dull empty life I’m set free; 
  For when  I met _ Je -- sus, He made me com -- plete; 
  He for -- got "the foolish" one I used to be. 
}

\score {
  <<
    \new ChordNames \chordNames
    \new FretBoards \chordNames
    \new Staff { \melody }
    \addlyrics { \verseone }
    \addlyrics { \versetwo }
  >>
  \layout { }
  \midi {
    \tempo 4=100
  }
}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "separate"; can you please explain what you are trying to get?

Comment: In many songbooks, there is a verse section and a chorus section. Rather than having the verse run into the chorus on the same line of the output. Some would add a label to the chorus, some to both, on the left of the staves. This means that the verse would have to end at the end of the line, rather than in the middle. 
This would seem to be most easily accomplished by having the two parts of the song be separate sections in the layout. I think this is possible, given some examples I have seen, but I'm unsure of how this is formatted.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be looking for the `\break` command, which forces a line break in the output at the point it is used. See http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/line-breaking

In recent LilyPond versions (2.23.x), you can add a label to a passage using `\sectionLabel "Chorus"` (perhaps in small caps: `\sectionLabel \markup \smallCaps "Chorus"`). In older versions, like 2.22 (the current stable version), you would "abuse" a rehearsal mark for that: `\mark "Chorus"`. By the way, you are using 2.20 which is not the latest stable version. Upgrading to at least 2.22 is recommended (and when you upgrade, be sure to use [convert-ly](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/usage/updating-files-with-convert_002dly) to make any necessary syntax changes automtically).

Answer (score 1):

Here’s two ways of doing something like this. The first one simply uses `\break` to separate Verses and Chorus into different systems:

```
\version "2.20.0"

\language "english"

\include "predefined-guitar-fretboards.ly"

\header {
  title = "I'm Free"
  composer = "William J. and Gloria Gaither"
}

global = {
  \key d \major
  \time 4/4
}
chordNames = \chordmode {
  \global
  % Chords follow here.
  r4 d1 g2. d1
  a1 a1 d1
  d1 g1 d1(d1)
  d2 a2. g2. d1
  d4 g1 d1. 
  d2 a1.. d1.
  g1. d1 d1
  d4 a2.a1. d1.
}
melody = \relative c' {
  \global
  % Music follows here.
  % allow mark being printed at the begin of the line
  \tweak break-align-symbols #'()
  \mark \markup \box "Verse"
  d8( e8) fs2. | fs8 fs8 g4 a4 b4 | a4 fs2. | %m1
  a4 a2 a4 | a8 a4 g4. fs4 | e1 | %m2
  d4 e8 fs8(fs2) | fs8 fs8 g4 a4  b4 | a2 a4 a4 | g1 |%m3
  b8 b8 b4 a2 | g4 fs4 fs4 e4| d1 | %m4
  
  \bar "||"
  \break
  
  \tweak break-align-symbols #'()
  %\tweak self-alignment-X #RIGHT
  \mark \markup \box "Chorus"
  a'4 b4 b8 b8 g4 | a4 b4 g4 fs4(fs1) %m5
  a4 a2 a8 a8 | g4 fs2 e4 | fs1 | %m6
  a4 a4 b2 | b8  b8 g4 a4  b8 b8 | a2 a4 a4 | fs1 | %m7
  a4 a2. | a4 g4 fs2 | fs4 e4 d2(d1) |

  \bar "|."
}

verseone = \lyricmode {
  % Lyrics follow here.
  So long I had searched for life’s mean -- ing, 
  En -- slaved by the world and my greed; 
  Then the door of the pri -- son was o -- pened by love, 
  For the ran -- som was paid, I was freed.
  I’m free from the fear of to -- mor -- row; 
  I’m free from the guilt of the past; 
  For I’ve trad -- ed my shack -- les for a glor -- i -- ous song; 
  I’m free, praise the Lord, free at last! 
}

versetwo = \lyricmode {
  I’m free from the guilt that I car -- ried, 
  From that dull empty life I’m set free; 
  For when  I met _ Je -- sus, He made me com -- plete; 
  He for -- got "the foolish" one I used to be. 
}

\score {
  <<
    \new ChordNames \chordNames
    \new FretBoards \chordNames
    \new Staff { \melody }
    \addlyrics { \verseone }
    \addlyrics { \versetwo }
  >>
  \layout { }
  \midi {
    \tempo 4=100
  }
}
```

Labelling is a bit hard here, because the FB diagrams.

The second option is to use different scores for separating both. This allows for some additional separation, like an indent for the chorus or even adding a slight spacer between verses and chorus:

```
\version "2.20.0"

\language "english"

\include "predefined-guitar-fretboards.ly"

\header {
  title = "I'm Free"
  composer = "William J. and Gloria Gaither"
}

global = {
  \key d \major
  \time 4/4
}
chordNamesA = \chordmode {
  \global
  % Chords follow here.
  r4 d1 g2. d1
  a1 a1 d1
  d1 g1 d1(d1)
  d2 a2. g2. d1
}
melodyA = \relative c' {
  \global
  % Music follows here.
  d8( e8) fs2. | fs8 fs8 g4 a4 b4 | a4 fs2. | %m1
  a4 a2 a4 | a8 a4 g4. fs4 | e1 | %m2
  d4 e8 fs8(fs2) | fs8 fs8 g4 a4  b4 | a2 a4 a4 | g1 |%m3
  b8 b8 b4 a2 | g4 fs4 fs4 e4| d1 | %m4
  
  \bar "||"
}

chordNamesB = \chordmode {
  d4 g1 d1. 
  d2 a1.. d1.
  g1. d1 d1
  d4 a2.a1. d1.
}
melodyB = \relative {
  % required for having the first bar number printed out
  \bar ""
  a'4 b4 b8 b8 g4 | a4 b4 g4 fs4(fs1) %m5
  a4 a2 a8 a8 | g4 fs2 e4 | fs1 | %m6
  a4 a4 b2 | b8  b8 g4 a4  b8 b8 | a2 a4 a4 | fs1 | %m7
  a4 a2. | a4 g4 fs2 | fs4 e4 d2(d1) |

  \bar "|."
}

verseone = \lyricmode {
  % Lyrics follow here.
  So long I had searched for life’s mean -- ing, 
  En -- slaved by the world and my greed; 
  Then the door of the pri -- son was o -- pened by love, 
  For the ran -- som was paid, I was freed. 
}

versetwo = \lyricmode {
  I’m free from the guilt that I car -- ried, 
  From that dull empty life I’m set free; 
  For when  I met _ Je -- sus, He made me com -- plete; 
  He for -- got "the foolish" one I used to be. 
}

chorus = \lyricmode {
  I’m free from the fear of to -- mor -- row; 
  I’m free from the guilt of the past; 
  For I’ve trad -- ed my shack -- les for a glor -- i -- ous song; 
  I’m free, praise the Lord, free at last!
}

\score {
  <<
    \new ChordNames \chordNamesA
    \new FretBoards \chordNamesA
    \new Staff \with { instrumentName = \markup \box \larger "Verse" } { \melodyA }
    \addlyrics { \verseone }
    \addlyrics { \versetwo }
  >>
  \layout { }
  \midi {
    \tempo 4=100
  }
}

%% Add a little space
\markup \vspace #1

\score {
  <<
    \new ChordNames \chordNamesB
    \new FretBoards \chordNamesB
    \new Staff \with { instrumentName = \markup \box \larger "Chorus" } { \melodyB }
    \addlyrics { \chorus }
  >>
  \layout {
    \context {
      \Score
      % have the Score start at bar number 14
      currentBarNumber = #14
    }
  }
  \midi {
    \tempo 4=100
  }
}
```